# How to use [class*="col-"] in scss module in nextjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js, css-modules

I've tried to make a responsive grid system in my `nextjs` web app using `scss module`,

```css
/* For desktop: */
.col-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}
.col-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
}
.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  [class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

But I've faced with an issue which tells me you cannot use `[class*="col-"]`:

```sh
error - ./pages/examples/test.module.scss:56:2
Syntax error: Selector "[class*=col-]" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)

  54 | @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  55 |   /* For mobile phones: */
> 56 |   [class*="col-"] {
     |  ^
  57 |     width: 100%;
  58 |   }
```

How can we fix this?

Comment: Even if that error wasn't there, it won't work because the classes will be hashed, and that attribute selector will not match anything. You can move these to a global CSS files. Or you can write `width:100%` for each `col` class. Since you are using SCSS, you can easily use flow control directives or mixins to accomplish this.

Comment: You are right, thank you. If it was not a global CSS (not like this example), what should we do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .row :global [class*="col-"] {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```